# Need some help regarding scenes in DrRacket

Tags: racket

I would like to create a scene with all my images on that one scene. I understand how to create a scene with one image. For example:

```
(define HEIGHT 800)

(define WIDTH 500)

(define (sceneblank x)
  (place-image blank 400 400 (empty-scene WIDTH HEIGHT "black"))
  ;blank being the image

(animate sceneblank)
```

But how can I continuously use the place image function to place images on that one scene?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested functions to place multiple images on one scene, like this:

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)

(define HEIGHT 800)
(define WIDTH 500)
(define BLANK-SCENE
  (empty-scene WIDTH HEIGHT "black"))

;; This function shows just the circle
(define (add-circle x scene)
  (place-image (circle 50 "solid" "red") x 400 scene))

;; This function shows just the square
(define (add-square x scene)
  (place-image (square 50 "solid" "blue") x 500 scene))

;; This shows both of them
(define (circle+square x)
  (add-circle x (add-square x BLANK-SCENE)))

(animate circle+square)
```